# Mixare iOS Integration

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

Good Day,

Does anybody know where I can find a guide on how to integrate the Mixare Augmented Reality Engine in to my iOS app? There isn't much documentation and it does exactly what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: There is demo available  here

https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone

you can look into sample application how it works

Answer (score 0):

If you download the source code for iPhone, you will find a nice demo app there as well. It shows how to do what you need, and it also forms a perfect base for a custom mixare app. Just pop in your own data, your UI, and your app is done.

https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone